# schtasks /change

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduling, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-task-scheduler

I wan't to change the repeat time from one task from 5 minutes to 1 minute.  The task is there:

Folder: \

HostName:                             ZSERVER

TaskName:                             \Check_IIS_Server

Next Run Time:                        04.10.2012 16:30:45

Status:                               Ready

Logon Mode:                           Interactive/Background

Last Run Time:                        04.10.2012 16:25:45

Last Result:                          0

Author:                               WACKER\createuser

Task To Run:                          powershell.exe powershell.exe -Noninteract
ive -Command "&{C:\Logfiles_Poly\Check_IIS_Server.ps1}"

Start In:                             N/A

Comment:                              N/A

Scheduled Task State:                 Enabled

Idle Time:                            Disabled

Power Management:                     Stop On Battery Mode, No Start On Batteries

Run As User:                          WACKER\Adminuser

Delete Task If Not Rescheduled:       Enabled

Stop Task If Runs X Hours and X Mins: 01:00:00

Schedule:                             Scheduling data is not available in this format.

Schedule Type:                        Daily

Start Time:                           N/A

Start Date:                           N/A

End Date:                             N/A

Days:                                 Every 1 day(s)

Months:                               N/A

Repeat: Every:                        0 Hour(s), 5 Minute(s)

Repeat: Until: Time:                  None

Repeat: Until: Duration:              24 Hour(s), 0 Minute(s)

Repeat: Stop If Still Running:        Disabled

Now my change command is, i wan't to edit the repeat time to one minute:

C:\Users\username>schtasks /change /tn "Check_IIS_Server_Poly" /ri 1
ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.

Why did I can't edit this job over command?

Thanks,
Horst

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide full path to the task, in your case it'll be `\Check_IIS_Server`. I don't see anything else that could be wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I create a task (schtasks /change /mo 1 /tn "Test") with repeat time one minute and edit the other settings manuell.
Horst